# last publish date of a tableau workbook using tabcmd commands

Tags: tableau-api, command-line-tool

how to know the history of publish dates of a tableau workbook that is present on tableau server with the help of tab command utility, I have checked for list of tab command utility but not able to figure.

Answer (score 1):

`Tabcmd` doesn't have a feature yet to extract the publish dates for any particular `Tableau` workbook. But we have `rest-api` for our rescue.
Using the workbooks views methods of the `Tableau Server REST API` you can do the operations such as -

1. Get or update the details of a specific workbook (createdAt,
   updatedAt, etc...)
2. Return a list of revision information (history)
   for the specified workbook

URI details

1. GET /api/api-version/sites/site-id/workbooks/workbook-id
2. GET
   /api/api-version/sites/site-id/workbooks/workbook-id/revisions

Also, if using `python` then we have `Tableau Server Client (TSC)` to interact with the `Tableau Server REST API` (and perform almost everything that can be done with the `REST API`).
Using the `TSC` library, you can get information about a specific workbook or all the workbooks on a site.
Using `workbooks.get(req_options=None)` method returns information about the workbooks on the site and `workbooks.get_by_id(workbook_id)` returns information about the specified workbook on the site.

More details [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_workbooksviews.htm) & [here](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is possible using tabcmd.

But you can get the first & last published date of a workbook using tableau server REST API to query a workbook and get created and last updated dates.
Look [here for details](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_Workbook%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Reference%7C_____77)